# IOS: Can I use ABAddressBook to store contact information outside the iPhones Contacts?

Tags: ios, class, contacts, abaddressbook

I'm wanting to store some contact information and allow the user to call/email the person instead of just looking up the info.  I don't want the contacts stored in the user's Address Book in their contacts though.  I want to keep it within the app only.  Can I use ABAddressBook for this or do I need to create my own classes to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address both your questions:

> Can I use ABAddressBook for this?

You cannot use ABAddressBook to store a separate contacts database. Here's an excerpt from the [ABAddressBook Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The ABAddressBook class provides a programming interface to the Address Book—a centralized database used by multiple applications to store contact and other personal information about people.

The database referred to here is a pre-specified database; there is no method or class to create a new one, as the whole Address Book framework provides access to a single database accessible to the user through the Contacts application.

> Do I need to create my own classes to accomplish this?

You would need to create a custom class for this. If you plan on supporting users with many, **many** contacts (in the thousands/high hundreds range), you probably would use an SQLite database. If you plan on supporting users with few contacts, you should probably use a .plist.

Usually, Objective-C programmers use the C library for SQLite directly, but now there is a great wrapper that you can find [here](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) called FMDB.

For info on the syntax and basics of SQLite, see the [SQLite Language Guide](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Lastly, here are a couple books on SQLite and database programming for iOS:

- (Apress) [Using SQLite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521189)
- (Wrox) [Professional iPhone and iPad Database Application Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470636173)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure did! Cleared some things up thanks! Quick question however... why do you recommend FMDB over Core Data... or are they separate things? Thanks!

Comment: @daveomcd FMDB is a wrapper around SQLite, while Core Data is a completely different way of persisting data. So yeah, they're completely different things.